# Natural Linking of Request and Response logs .NET Core app

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to link my request and response logs by GUID. Either i get the same GUID for every request and response, or i get a completely different one fore every request and response. What i need is for the linked Requests and responses to have the Same GUID, but be different to all other requests an responses. Is it even possible to do this with my current structure?

```
public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware
    {
        
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly RecyclableMemoryStreamManager _recyclableMemoryStreamManager;

        public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware>();
            _recyclableMemoryStreamManager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            await LogRequest(context);
            await LogResponse(context);

        }

        private async Task LogRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();

            await using var requestStream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
            await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestStream);


            var Request = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
                {"Http Request Information", $"{DateTime.UtcNow}"},
                {"ID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
                {"IP", $"{context.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress}" },
                {"Schema", context.Request.Scheme},
                {"Path", context.Request.Path},
                {"QueryString", $"{context.Request.QueryString}"},
                {"Request Body", ReadStreamInChunks(requestStream)}
            };

            var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request, Formatting.None);

            _logger.LogInformation(requestJson);

            context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        }


        private async Task LogResponse(HttpContext context)
        {
            var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

            await using var responseBody = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
            context.Response.Body = responseBody;

            await _next(context);

            context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var text = await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var Response = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
                {"Http Response Information", $"{DateTime.UtcNow}"},
                {"ID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
                {"IP", $"{context.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress}" },
                {"Schema", context.Request.Scheme},
                {"Path", context.Request.Path },
                {"QueryString", $"{context.Request.QueryString}"},
                {"Response Body", text}
            };

            var responseJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Response, Formatting.None);

            _logger.LogInformation(responseJson);

            await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
        }

        private static string ReadStreamInChunks(Stream stream)
        {
            const int readChunkBufferLength = 4096;

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            using var textWriter = new StringWriter();
            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            var readChunk = new char[readChunkBufferLength];
            int readChunkLength;

            do
            {
                readChunkLength = reader.ReadBlock(readChunk, 0, readChunkBufferLength);
                textWriter.Write(readChunk, 0, readChunkLength);
            } while (readChunkLength > 0);

            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd extend request and response json objects and add there some ID fields and fill the with the same Guid:

```
public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware
    {
        
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly RecyclableMemoryStreamManager _recyclableMemoryStreamManager;

        public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware>();
            _recyclableMemoryStreamManager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            await LogRequest(context, guid);
            await LogResponse(context, guid);

        }

        private async Task LogRequest(HttpContext context, Guid guid)
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();

            await using var requestStream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
            await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestStream);


            var Request = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
                {"Request ID", guid.ToString()}
                {"Http Request Information", $"{DateTime.UtcNow}"},
                {"ID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
                {"IP", $"{context.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress}" },
                {"Schema", context.Request.Scheme},
                {"Path", context.Request.Path},
                {"QueryString", $"{context.Request.QueryString}"},
                {"Request Body", ReadStreamInChunks(requestStream)}
            };

            var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request, Formatting.None);

            _logger.LogInformation(requestJson);

            context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        }


        private async Task LogResponse(HttpContext context, Guid guid)
        {
            var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

            await using var responseBody = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
            context.Response.Body = responseBody;

            await _next(context);

            context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var text = await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var Response = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
                {"Request ID", guid.ToString()}
                {"Http Response Information", $"{DateTime.UtcNow}"},
                {"ID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
                {"IP", $"{context.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress}" },
                {"Schema", context.Request.Scheme},
                {"Path", context.Request.Path },
                {"QueryString", $"{context.Request.QueryString}"},
                {"Response Body", text}
            };

            var responseJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Response, Formatting.None);

            _logger.LogInformation(responseJson);

            await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
        }

        private static string ReadStreamInChunks(Stream stream)
        {
            const int readChunkBufferLength = 4096;

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            using var textWriter = new StringWriter();
            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            var readChunk = new char[readChunkBufferLength];
            int readChunkLength;

            do
            {
                readChunkLength = reader.ReadBlock(readChunk, 0, readChunkBufferLength);
                textWriter.Write(readChunk, 0, readChunkLength);
            } while (readChunkLength > 0);

            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there's a specific principle you "link" your requests and responses, but assuming it's stock standard asp.net core app and you work within user request, I believe it is possible to inject [scoped services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scoped) into your middleware.
So, suppose you create a service with something these lines:

```
class GuidProvider {
   public string CorrelationId {get; private set;}
   public GuidProvider() {
      CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
   }
}
```

you'd register it in `Startup`:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(GuidProvider));
```

and inject into your middleware constructor:

````
public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(..., GuidProvider guidProvider) 
{ 
   guidProvider.CorrelationId; // should stay the same within request 
   ... 
}```
````